# Can I convert a checklist inside a card into a new card?

Tags: trello

I created a card with several checklists in it.

As the number of lists increased, I wanted to spin off some of them. I can convert one of the items in the checklist into a separate card, but I cannot convert the whole checklist into another card.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't really seem to match the text. Do you want to make just the title into a new card, or do you want the checklist copied into another card?

Comment: @RichArmstrong: you are right. It is not clear. I want to covert the whole checklist into a new card.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible. Though, we are working on copyable checklists, so you'd likely be able to copy the list to a new card.

Answer (score 9):

You can select all the text of the checklist items, starting over the checklist to avoid the drag and drop area. Then, insert the text into a new card. Push <kbd>enter</kbd> on the keyboard, Trello will ask you to make single cards out of every line, say yes, then archive every second card with the <kbd>c</kbd> key. Voila.

Comment: The cut and paste works great.  But why would you archive every second card?  Perhaps it is cleaner these days (I see the answer is 4 years old) and no longer creates extra cards.

Comment: It used to create empty cards from the empty lines.

Comment: Works perfectly.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I did not need to archive every second card with `c` -- so it works perfectly for me. (I'm also a text-editing wiz, too, and I used an intermediate vim-text-editing "buffer," so maybe that helps.) Thanks @Alex!

Comment: Though it's much better than converting every item individually, this does lose formatting like `code` of the items

Answer (score 7):

You can create a new card, and when adding a checklist "Copy" any checklist from the old card. Then you can go back to the original card and delete the checklist.

Comment: The only caveat is that you have to re-check items that were checked. However, this is very simple, considering it is in the same order. I think this is the best way to do this, and least error prone. Until they develop the "turn checklist into card" button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create checklist from checklist. Also Cards from Checklist

**This is kind of a hack.**

To start with follow these steps:

- Copy the list as the text selection

[image: Copied Text]

- Paste it in Excel (for windows) / Numbers (for Mac)

[image: Copied data in excel]

- Now paste data in the new checklist created [inside **Add an item...** textfield]. And **Press Enter**
- **or** to create cards. Paste data in new card and press enter

  - It will ask to create card for each. Press yes / Enter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the card with check list
2. Press F12 to open browser console
3. Copy the code below and paste in console
4. ie. getListText(0)

   @param elIdx Index of check list on card (first list index is 0)

   @param order true | undefined [optional] Set to true if you want to add line number to result

Here the code

```
let getListText = (elIdx, order) => {
    const arr = []
    $(`.checklist:eq(${elIdx})  .checklist-item-details-text`).each((idx, el) => {
        const text = $(el).text();
        const ordering = (order) ? (idx + 1) + `. ` : ``;
        arr.push(`${ordering}${text}\n`);
    });
    console.log(arr.join(''));
}
```

and the result will appear in the console